# What is the difference between fsExtra.pathExists and fsExtra.exists?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, fs-extra

I know exists is deprecated in fs but it is able in fs-extra.

I used both fsExtra.pathExists and  fsExtra.exists.

But I could not find the difference.

They performe same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not much difference between these two methods.

`fs-extra` is a superset of `fs`, inheriting [all](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra#usage) its methods, so `fsExtra.exists` is the same as `fs.exists`. And as you said it's deprecated.

The difference between `exists()` and `pathExists()` lies in the [signature](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/master/docs/pathExists.md#pathexistsfile-callback) of the functions.

> Like fs.exists, but with a normal callback signature (err, exists).

Internally, `fs` native module use a try catch block, while `fs-extra` use a Promise style. And they both use `fs.access()` method to determine if the specified file is accessible.

And yes, they both have the same use.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I am sorry, I am Japanese and not good at English. What is the word signature means? You mean just a difference of name of functions?

Comment: fsExtra.exists and fsExtra.pathExists both return Promise. So, I thought it's same.

Comment: Sorry now I understand what you mean. I will put edit on question to confirm.

Comment: Yes basically, the callback version of `pathExists()` add the `err` param while `exists()` doesn't. As said in documentation, "The parameters for this callback are not consistent with other Node.js callbacks". That's why it is deprecated.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I can't  understand why fs.exists callback is not consistent with other Node.js callbacks and fsExtra.pathExists callback is consistent with other Node.js callbacks.  There are no difference I think.

Comment: In Node.js, the callback function usually takes 2 arguments: `(err, data)`. `fs.exists` has only one argument. As the [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) says: "Normally, the first parameter to a Node.js callback is an err parameter, optionally followed by other parameters. The fs.exists() callback has only one boolean parameter."

Comment: Hmm thank you so much you are very knowledgeable. I understand.